# How can i block all ssh connections except the ones from a specific source in firewalld and also log the denied ssh connections

Tags: logging, ssh, firewalld

How can i block all ssh connections except ones from 192.168.1.1 in firewalld and at the same time log the the refused ssh connections?

I tried:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --set-default-zone=drop
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-source=192.168.1.1 --zone=trusted
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=ssh --zone=trusted
```

this blocks them but doesn't log the denied ssh connections.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the logging of denied packets in */etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf*

```
LogDenied=all
```

or on the command line:

```
firewall-cmd --set-log-denied=all
```